# ¿Qué se hace con la gente que menosprecia las preguntas en Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: discusión

Bueno, es un pregunta en general de la comunidad y que ha sucedido no solo una sino muchas veces, Stack Overflow en español/inglés en la cual todos  compartimos conocimiento aunque sea mínimo pero compartimos y ayudamos a los demás sin pedir un beneficio monetario, pero he notado a personas, lo digo en general, no apuntaré a nadie, pero menosprecian la pregunta de usuarios que su nivel de conocimiento es bajo. En vez de dar una recomendación al usuario, le dan un punto negativo a la pregunta solo porque en su opinión está mal o algo parecido. Si para ellos está mal, ¿Por qué no le ayudan al autor de la pregunta editando su pregunta correctamente en vez de darle un punto negativo? Todos empezamos desde cero y en mi opinión a esas personas que solo menosprecian las preguntas de los usuarios de Stack Overflow, etc.

Comento esto solo para que la comunidad sea pasiva y nos podamos ayudar entre todos en nuestros problemas.

Comment: Dos recomendaciones, 1.- Si tienes algunos ejemplos concretos ponlos, esto será mejor para entender puntualmente la situación que intentas transmitir a la comunidad. 2.- La redacción y ortografía juega un papel crucial al momento de publicar una pregunta, se puede mal entender lo que originalmente deseas compartir con la comunidad.

Comment: Lo siento amigo :( dejame buscar el comentario que vi.

Comment: No hay porqué sentirlo :)

Comment: Para eso son los votos, para dar una opinión. Todo lo demás de "menospreciar", "no ayudar", etc., son suposiciones personales. Ni siquiera hay forma de saber (con certeza) quién vota negativo.

Comment: La flechita del voto negativo indica _Esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación; es confusa o poco útil (hacer clic de nuevo para deshacer la acción)_. La mayoría de las veces que obtienes un voto negativo, es bueno plantearse si es porque está pasando exactamente eso.

Comment: No es conveniente editar las preguntas cuando no es claro lo que buscan. Uno no puede llegar a adivinar cuál es el problema que tiene quien pregunta. La comunidad es pasiva pero, así como todos compartimos lo poco que sabemos, esperamos que haya esfuerzo en quien llega a buscar. No es un servicio de escritura de código.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> pero he notado a personas, lo digo en general, no apuntaré a nadie, pero menosprecian la pregunta de usuarios que su nivel de conocimiento es bajo

Mi percepción es un poco la contraria. En Stack Overflow en Español se ven muchas preguntas básicas aceptadas por la comunidad, con muchos puntos y muchas respuestas (el sitio en inglés es un mundo aparte)...

Pero puede que sea sólo eso, mi percepción: que preguntas como ésta se repitan cada X meses podría ser una señal, pero creo que en general no es el caso.

Sí que creo que estamos siendo algo estrictos con los cierres de preguntas, quizás habría que tener más paciencia con los usuarios nuevos. Eso no quiere decir que las preguntas que acaban cerradas estén mal cerradas, pero podría ver cómo un usuario nuevo no comprende el porqué.

> ¿Por qué no le ayudan al autor de la pregunta editando su pregunta correctamente en vez de darle un punto negativo?

Porque no es su trabajo.

Sí, sé que puede sonar mal o triste, pero es la realidad: el trabajo de tener la pregunta correcta es del que la escribe, no del que la lee.

La persona que lee la pregunta puede corregir la ortografía, o el formato del texto/código, o mover comentarios/snippets a la pregunta en sí... pero poco más. El lector no sabe cuál es el código o el caso particular que el OP quiere. Y si OP no muestra interés alguno, es injusto que sea el lector el que tenga que hacer investigación y arreglar la pregunta.

De nuevo, sé que puede sonar mal, pero también es necesario que sea el propio OP el que edite para que aprenda por sí mism@ cómo debe ser. De lo contrario nos encontraríamos con usuarios "experimentados" que sólo saben hacer malas preguntas (y tenemos algunos de esos).

> Comento esto solo para que la comunidad sea pasiva y nos podamos ayudar entre todos en nuestros problemas.

Me imagino que lo que quieres es que la comunidad sea activa y no pasiva; de lo contrario, poco nos vamos a poder ayudar :)

Comment: De acuerdo en todo. Excelente respuesta a una (en mi opinión) mala pregunta... Un comentario sobre tu percepción: las preguntas verborrágicas de este estilo ocurren recurrentemente en *todos* los Metas... Y un punto que agregaría: que alguien esté iniciándose en programación y que sea nuevo en el sitio no lo excusan de redactar bien una pregunta y plantear un problema bien descrito: no le impiden hacer *una buena pregunta*.

Comment: @Mariano Ser nuevo no te impide hacer una buena pregunta pero tampoco te lo facilita. No sucede lo mismo con ser veterano, eso sí te facilita hacer una buena pregunta. Es por tanto normal tener diferentes expectativas de un novato que de un veterano y actuar en consecuencia.

Answer (score 2):

Por favor tengan presente que la calidad de las preguntas tiene que ver con el dominio del lenguaje escrito, no con el tiempo que se ha estado abonado a un foro. Más aún, muchísimos usuarios de *internet* tienen muy baja o casi nula formación académica. La humanidad no es culta, ni la vuelve culta, leer preguntas y respuestas. Más aún, estamos en un mundo en que la educación está orientada a que la gran mayoría de la gente se dedique a oficios, relativamente mecánicos; y ello hace que la calidad de la expresión escrita que se encuentra en los foros sea sistemáticamente baja. De modo que no se puede andar condenando a los que 'malescriben' no importa si llevan años o días participando.

Acepto la tesis de que no es tarea del lector convertir en pregunta adecuada lo que lee. Pero, si la pregunta malformada es suficientemente inteligible y va a motivar respuestas valiosas, se la debe corregir para enriquecer el foro. Y, la ponderación, de si merece o no edición, viene de quién está dispuesto a "darse la pela" de editarla; y, si en un tiempo razonable, no encuentra editores dispuestos a salvarla, se puede considerar "llegada la hora de los verdugos". Esto, podría convertirse en criterio, tácito o explícito, para tratar las preguntas. Más aún, en mi **recorrido inicial** no encontré una indicación a propósito del tiempo que es razonable mantener abierta una pregunta que no ha recibido respuesta. Y, no se, cómo lo vean ustedes, pero me parece que hace falta un curso de acción: reformularla de modo que pueda invitar a ser respondida, simplemente cerrarla, o en casos especiales, como preguntas que requieran conocimientos especiales para ser atendidas: redirigirla a una sección de preguntas fuera del nivel promedio del foro.

Comment: Si bien en términos genéricos vale calificar SOes como foro a algunos usuarios no nos gusta que se le llame así por las formas vinculadas al término, particularmente  el de realizar publicaciones principalmente basadas en opiniones carentes de un sustento basado en fuentes fidedignas o experiencia de "grado profesional".

Comment: Con respecto al curso de acción ya tenemos [¿Qué debo hacer si nadie contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) y si mal no recuerdo también algunos [meta-tag:faq] y en lo que respecta a "fuera del nivel promedio del foro" para eso se muestra arriba del espacio para publicar una respuesta "¿Conoces a alguien que pueda responder? Comparte un enlace a esta pregunta por correo electrónico, Google+, Twitter o Facebook."

Comment: Me pregunto si así sería que te llegó la invitación a SOes :)

Answer (score -9):

Son personas enfermas de vanidad, se les ha subido el ego al corazón, si su estocada es ligera solo lo dejo vivir, tarde o temprano se dará cuenta de su postura pretenciosa e incluso discriminatoria en la mayoría de los casos y le resultara vergonzoso... ya que si su estocada es muy fuerte y tengo capacidad de citarlo, como en un foro (Aquí uno se enfoca más a la resolución del problema que al flameo y discusión) usualmente le pregunto ¿Tienes mucho ego? Y generalmente se ponen a insultar a la defensiva... eso también me ocurre mucho en la vida real, y la respuesta de las personas engreídas es sumamente curiosa... algunos voltean al cielo y recapacitan, otros se enfadan y te ofenden, otros cínicos admiten que sí... otros te amenazan... hay de todo.

Finalmente, si el ataque de vanidad es sumamente alto y está afectando vidas inocentes al grado de físicamente... entonces es necesario intervenir... pero eso ya es otra historia muy aparte y un caso muy extremo y raro.