# ¿Cómo hacer preguntas de manera correcta y evitar que te la cierren?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, propuesta-de-faq

Suele suceder en [Stackoverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)  **la mayor parte del tiempo** que los nuevos usuarios crean preguntas malas donde se nota el poco interés/investigación previa en Google a cosas que lo podrías solucionar con una simple búsqueda y se deben editar quitando cosas innecesarias a la pregunta en concreto

> entonces, ¿Cómo podrías crear una buena pregunta y evitar que te den
>   voto negativo?

Comment: Aplaudo tu aportación. De todas maneras, existen en el sitio numerosos recursos sobre como hacer una buena pregunta, desde el centro de ayuda hasta numerosos posts aqui en meta.

Comment: Considero que que sería más apropiado usar [meta-tag:soporte] que [meta-tag:discusión] por ser una pregunta autorespondida. Encuanto a [meta-tag:wiki-de-comunidad] supongo que la has agregado por el comentario a la respuesta en la que se opinó que debía ser wiki de comunidad pero para hacer una pregunta wiki de comunidad se requiere la intervención de un moderador ♦, (por cierto, a [meta-tag:wiki-de-comunidad] le falta guía de uso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que mi post sea útil para todo el mundo.

**Antes de preguntar**

Antes de hacer una pregunta en [es.stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/), deberías hacer lo siguiente:

- Intenta encontrar una respuesta leyendo la documentación.(si no la encuentras o se te hace complicado entender la documentación, te sugiero preguntar aquí, pero evita usar títulos como:

  > Necesito ayuda a entender un concepto basico de equis lenguaje

  o

  > Que significa `var` en javascript

  y mejor pregunta:

  > en qué situación se podría usar equis función?

  o

  > cual es la diferencia entre equis función y equis función

  )
- Intenta encontrar una respuesta buscando en la web(si no lo encuentras o no te convence, te recomiendo preguntar aquí)
- Intenta encontrar la respuesta preguntándole a un amigo con más 
  experiencia (me refiero a dudas basicas o tutoriales,etc)

  A qué me refiero con la pregunta de arriba? evitar este tipo de preguntas :

  > me gustaría, que me pudierais indicar un buen tutorial de Spring. Si es por youtube, mejor.
  >
  > Muchas gracias

  [es esta pregunta - pero quizá sea eliminada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/184106/donde-encontrar-un-buen-tutorial-spring)

  Cuando hagas tu pregunta, destaca el hecho de que ya has hecho todo esto; esto ayudará a establecer que no eres una esponja vaga y que sólo estás desperdiciando el tiempo de los demás.

**Prepara tu pregunta**.

Piensa en ella. Las preguntas precipitadas reciben respuestas precipitadas, o ni siquiera eso. Cuanto más hagas para demostrar que has puesto pensamiento y esfuerzo en resolver tu problema antes de pedir ayuda, más cerca estarás de recibirla realmente.

Lo anterior lo comento porque he visto preguntas (**las cuales han sido 
  eliminadas por poca investigacion de parte del usuario  en su edicion)**

Quizá se te venga a la mente, deberíamos editar su pregunta para mejorarla, pero yo te comentaría sencillamente:

> Porque no es nuestro trabajo.
>
> Sí, sé que puede sonar mal o triste, pero es la realidad: el trabajo
>   de tener la pregunta correcta es del que la escribe, no del que la
>   lee.

como lo comenta uno de los moderadores : [alvaro montoro](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro)

el cual lo comentó en una pregunta mía de hace mucho **cuando era demasiado nuevo** y hacía muchos equivocaciones porque estaba acostumbrado en foros de internet a preguntar cosas así y no conocía como funciona stack exchange.
pst:  soy todavia nuevo puede que me equivoque todavia.

[Esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2142/qu%C3%A9-se-hace-con-la-gente-que-menosprecia-las-preguntas-en-stack-overflow-en-esp)

Nunca asumas que tienes derecho a una respuesta. No lo tienes. Te ganarás una respuesta, si te la ganas haciendo una pregunta excelente o interesante y que haga pensar que sea única en stackoverflow — una que contribuya grandemente  a la comunidad.

Por otra parte, un muy buen comienzo es dejar claro que puedes y quieres participar en el proceso de desarrollar la solución.

por ejemplo planteando cosas como:

> "¿Tiene alguien alguna pista?"
>
> "¿Qué le falta a mi ejemplo?"

tendrás más probabilidades de ser respondidas,porque estás dejando claro que estás realmente deseoso de completar el proceso si alguien simplemente te orienta en la dirección correcta.

**Cuando preguntes**

Ten cuidado al elegir dónde planteas tu pregunta y que etiquetas usar. Seguramente nadie te responderá si no usas la etiqueta adecuada.

Por ejemplo, si mi problema esta en el [mvc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) y yo solo agrego la etiqueta 
[patrones-de-diseño](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patrones-de-dise%c3%b1o) y no la etiqueta [mvc](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc).

**Escribe de manera clara respetando la ortografía y la gramática**

Aunque esto debería resultar obvio, es importante expresar tu pregunta de manera clara.

- No ESCRIBAS TODO EN MAYÚSCULAS, eso se lee como si estuvieses
  gritando, y es considerado una falta de educación por algunos usuarios
- Si escribes como una preguntas con faltas de ortografía probablemente te ignorarán.

  Escribir una pregunta así:

  > komo krear un programita pala lee info

  es el beso de la muerte absoluto y te garantiza que no recibirás otra cosa que un silencio sepulcral (o, si tienes suerte, un montón de  sarcasmo).

**Usa títulos específicos y con sentido**

la cabecera de una pregunta es tu oportunidad de oro para atraer la atención de expertos, no la desperdicies en balbuceos como "**Por favor ayúdame**" o "**Necesito ayuda en..**" (de "**POR FAVOR AYÚDAME!!!**" ya ni hablamos).

Mala pregunta:

> ¡AYUDA! ¡El código no funciona en mi portátil!**

Excelente pregunta:

> ¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?

**Sé preciso e informativo sobre tu problema**

- Describe los síntomas de tu problema o error con cuidado y claramente.
- Describe el entorno en el que ocurre (máquina, S.O., aplicación, loquesea).
- Describe la investigación que llevaste a cabo para encontrar una 
  posible respuesta al problema antes de hacer la pregunta.
- Describe los pasos de diagnóstico que llevaste a cabo e intentaste
  solucionar el problema tú mismo antes de formular la pregunta.
- Describe cualquier cambio reciente en tu ordenador o combinación de 
  software que pueda resultar relevante.

**Describe los síntomas del problema, no tus suposiciones**

No es útil preguntar a los demás usuarios de stackoverflow lo que tú crees que está causándote el problema. (*Si tus teorías de diagnóstico fueran tan fiables, ¿estarías pidiendo ayuda?*) 
Por esto, asegúrate de que únicamente comentas los síntomas de lo que va mal (**errores de consola**) y no tus interpretaciones o teorías.

Ejemplos:

Mala:

> Me salen errores SIG11 durante la compilación del núcleo, y sospecho
>   que haya podido romperse un hilo en uno de los circuitos de la placa
>   base. ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de comprobar eso?

Buena:

> Mi K6/233 ensamblado por mí con una placa base FIC-PA2007 (chipset VIA
>   Apollo VP2) con 256MB Corsair PC133 SDRAM empieza a tener frecuentes
>   errores SIG11 sobre unos 20 minutos después de haberlo arrancado
>   durante el curso de compilaciones del núcleo, pero nunca durante los
>   primeros 20 minutos. Si reinicio no se reinicia el reloj, pero si lo
>   apago durante la noche sí. Pasar toda la RAM a la partición de
>   intercambio no ha servido de nada. A continuación os pongo la parte
>   relevante del registro de una típica sesión de compilación.

**Describe los síntomas de tu problema en orden cronológico**

Las pistas más útiles para averiguar qué ha ido mal se encuentran a menudo en los acontecimientos inmediatamente anteriores. Por esto, deberías describir con precisión lo que hiciste, y lo que hizo la máquina, hasta el momento fatídico.

Si el programa en cuestión tiene opciones de diagnóstico intenta pensar cuidadosamente en elegir opciones que puedan añadir información de depuración útil para la transcripción.

**Evita las preguntas insustanciales**

Resiste la tentación de preguntas semánticamente nulas como *"¿Puede ayudarme alguien?"*

**primero**: si has escrito la descripción de tu problema de manera medianamente competente, ese tipo de preguntas pueden ser consideras como  muy baja calidad o como poco investigada.

**La cortesía nunca hiere, e incluso a veces hasta ayuda.**

> Sé cortés deja claro que aprecias el tiempo que emplea la gente
>   ayudándote gratis.

**Concluye con una breve respuesta sobre la solución si la has encontrado**

Agrega una solución tras haber resuelto el problema tu mismo y agradece a todos los que te ayudaron o lo intentaron; hazles saber cómo acabó todo y agradéceles de nuevo su ayuda.

**Si no entiendes una respuesta**

Si no entiendes la respuesta, no devuelvas inmediatamente comentando.

Por ejemplo, supón que te digo: *"Suena como si tuvieses un error en el `if else`."* Entonces:

He aquí una mala pregunta: *"¿Qué es un `if else`?"*

estos comentarios son innecesarios.

He aquí una buena pregunta:

> "Está bien, he leído la página del lenguaje y los `if else` son muy usados para comparar variables . ¿Existe otra manera de validar estas variables sin usar `if else`?"

**Preguntas que no debes hacer o mejor dicho no deberías hacer son rápidamente tomadas como mal pregunta y votadas para un cierre.**

- P: ¿Dónde puedo encontrar el programa X?

  investigando un poco el mejor sitio para este tipo de pregunta seria este:
  [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) - en ingles - pero ten cuidado en no hacer preguntas de mala calidad
- P: Tengo problemas con mi máquina en Windows. ¿Podríais ayudarme?

el mejor sitio para este tipo de pregunta podria ser:
[superuser](https://superuser.com) - en ingles - pero ten cuidado en no hacer preguntas de mala calidad
 - P: Tengo problemas al instalar Linux o X. ¿Podríais ayudarme?

el mejor sitio para este tipo de pregunta podria ser :[unix & linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) - en ingles - pero ten cuidado en no hacer preguntas de mala calidad

- P: ¿Cual es el mejor sitio para aprender Java?

**Buenas y malas preguntas**

> Mala: ¿Dónde puedo encontrar un tutorial para crear un sitio web?
>
> Buena: He usado Google para intentar solucionar este problema en mi sitio web que no
>   me permite que se vea bien en todos los equipos, estoy usando media
>   query para hacerlo responsive el sitio, agrego mi codigo abajo y lo
>   que he intentado.

Espero que le ayude a evitar preguntar cosas que no tiene ninguna relevancia en stackoverflow, como buscar tutoriales  o recomendaciones de software/cual librería es mejor(*porque esta basada en opiniones personales*)

[fuente - en ingles](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

**Esta es un traducción del articulo en ingles a español.**

**si tienes alguna opinion diferente o algo que quisieras agregar con 
  gusto puedes responder o comentar tu sugerencia, todas son aceptadas.**

Comment: Me he permitido editar esta respuesta para mejorar el formato y aclarar algunas cosas que en mi opinión no se entendían bien. Creo que deberías revisar el párrafo _Si no entiendes una respuesta_ ya que no se muy bien que quieres decir en el. Por otro lado, pones como ejemplo de buena pregunta `¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?`, lo que en mi criterio puede tal vez considerarse como _demasiado amplia_.

Comment: @Pikoh la agrege esta pregunta porque fue una de las mas votadas en stackoverflow solo fue un ejemplo.

Comment: Considero que esto debería ser un Wiki de comunidad ;)

Comment: @Phi y como la puedo convertir en Wiki? yo solo agrege la etiqueta Wiki porque es las cercana a ella.

Comment: @simon gracias por tu excelente contribución!. Hay que recordar que muchos de los nuevos usuarios no acceden a ver las publicaciones en meta, por lo tanto hay que seguir orientandolos y tener paciencia así como lo has hecho hasta el día de hoy.