# ¿Cuál es la variante del español más adecuada en Meta?

Tags: discusión, idioma-español

Un usuarió editó [una pregunta mía](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3583/83) (**lo cual se lo agradezco**)  agregando la siguiente palabra: `podríais`. Entiendo que es una palabra  de España. Nótese que yo hice la pregunta agregando: [podrías](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/podr%C3%ADas).

Entiendo que existe mucha gente de España y de Hispanoamérica aquí y el vocabulario que usan es algo diferente.

Mi pregunta es: **¿Por qué fue editada mi pregunta si yo agregué correctamente una palabra bien en la pregunta?**

[image]

Quizá sea un simple detalle sin importancia, pero podría un futuro usuario entrar a ver la pregunta y no entender lo que significa a primera vista la palabra (**puede existir la posibiidad que un usuario jamás haya escuchado esa palabra hasta este momento, conozco amigos que me han preguntado qué significa y no son ignorantes**). Y no solo esa palabra sino varias (no las tengo a la mano).

**Lo comento para que todas las preguntas sean entendibles por todo el mundo, ya sean de Hispanoamérica o de otra parte.**

Comment: Según las [revisiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3583/revisions), tu hiciste la pregunta utilizando la palabra _podríais_. Por otro lado nunca se deben editar los localismos, por ejemplo en Argentina algunos dirán _podés_, no se debe cambiar nunca a _puedes_, lo mismo para todas las palabras, las correcciones deben ser solo para la ortografía y para mejorar el entendimiento de la pregunta/respuesta. No así para las páginas oficiales de documentación, ahí se mantiene un español neutro.

Comment: De hecho, si te das cuenta, todas las ediciones son de correcciones ortográficas, nadie topó la palabra _podríais_ por lo mismo que te mencioné anteriormente :)

Comment: @KacosPro yo usando podriais? mm que raro vere  la pregunta

Comment: Si :) [para muestra un botón](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3583/1)

Comment: Relacionado [¿Cómo de estrictos debemos ser al editar diferentes variedades del español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/51/65)

Comment: Estoy mirando el [historial de revisiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3583/revisions). En la revisión 4 @Rubén sustituyó _podrias_ por _podrías_ (añadió la tilde, vaya). En la revisión 6, tuya, modificaste _podríais_ por _podrías_. ¿A cuál te refieres?

Comment: @KacosPro Con mucho respeto para Simon, pero esta pregunta me recordó a [esta imagen](http://i49.tinypic.com/2m5yqur.jpg). Simon, probablemente la palabra la cambio un corrector ortográfico, por eso agregaste tu la palabra "podríais". Por cierto agregaste una imagen de una edición mía, pero mi edición fue la corrección de un error gramatical.

Answer (score 2):

## Todas

El español es un lenguaje muy rico y con muchas variantes. Todas hermosas.

Además, lo importante es que tu pregunta sea para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo. Que muestre esfuerzo, sea clara y concreta. Si tiene un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable mejor que mejor. Cumpliendo esto tu pregunta debe ser bienvenida en cualquier variante. Fallando en todo esto la pregunta no va a ser muy bien recibida sea cual sea la variante del español que uses. Algo similar aplica a las respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

## Resumen

Es muy loable tu interés de que las publicaciones sean entendibles por los hablantes de todas las variantes del español. Lo que debemos hacer todos es hacer nuestro mejor esfuerzo para que nuestras propias publicaciones sean claras y en la medida de lo posible colaborar para mejorar las publicaciones de los demás siempre y cuando dichas mejoras sean significativas.

## Explicación

La pregunta no es del todo una buena pregunta pues el título dice una cosa y el cuerpo del mensaje otra.

### Sobre el título

> ¿Cuál es la variante del español más adecuada en Meta?

Ninguna o como dijo Jose Antonio Dura Olmos en su [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3599/65), todas. En otras palabras,  la variante a utilizar depende del autor de la publicación, con excepción tal vez de las publicaciones wiki en la que los más apropiado podría ser usar *[español neutro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_neutro)* pues estas publicaciones en principio se desea la colaboración de la mayor cantidad de usuarios. La salvedad es que sea una variante válida para ser utilizada en un ámbito profesional afín a la temática del sitio.

### Sobre la otra pregunta

> Mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué fue editada mi pregunta si yo agregué correctamente una palabra bien en la pregunta?

Si te refieres a la [revisión 4](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3583/4), la cual yo realicé, los cambios no tenían la intención de cambiar la variante del español sino de corregir varios errores gramaticales y ortográficos desde mi percepción en ese momento auxiliado únicamente por el corrector de Chrome para Windows el cual lo tengo configurado en español y para obtener sugerencias de Google.

En cuanto a `podríais` no la cambié yo.

## Referencias

- [Modelo de conjugación verbal de poder](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal#n46)
- [¿Cómo podemos sugerir que las ediciones sean más sustanciales en la cola de "ediciones sugeridas"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1485/65)